# How to uninstall or remove XNView Multi Platform in 17.10?

Tags: xnview

I have installed XNView Multi Platform in Ubuntu 17.10, Now I am sick of it, I want to permanently uninstall or remove it from my computer.
Help!

Comment: How did you install it, via apt or make?

Comment: I have installed it using command on Terminal. sudo apt - get install xnview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you used `sudo apt-get install xnview` to install use this:

```
sudo apt-get purge xnview
```

to uninstall and get rid of all configuration files it created.